# How to apply bold + italic rich text formatting in XLIFF

Tags: localization, xliff

I see that XLIFF specification allows applying rich text formatting, and it even provides examples using `xlf:b` (bold) and `xlf:i` (italic). So that it can be used like this:

`<source>A line of text in<pc type="fmt" subType="xlf:b">paragraph</pc>.</source>`

What I can't find is how to correctly apply both bold and italic at the same time?

Any help greatly appeciated.